# 3D rotation of XYZ coordinates - Wrong results in certain angles?

Tags: vb.net, math, 3d, rotation

Please bear with me I´m a newbie in programming and I´m trying to learn how to rotate a 3D point (XYZ) around 0,0,0 and later I´ll try to improve my code to allow rotation around an arbitrary point (XYZ).

I´m starting with VB and after extensive searches here and in the Web, I could not find an explanation for my problem. I´m an almost 40 years old trying to learn math and programming, so please bear with me because it will take time for me to digest all the math side for these problems.

Basically, I´m trying to write an algorithm to rotate a 3D point, however, while it seems that with some angles my code works, with some others I just get weird funky numbers that are probable correct in some aspect, but I can´t find the flaw in the code. I´ve been looking into this for days and tried multiple approaches, but I´m just not being able to spot the error.

This is the UI for my little app. The original coordinates are entered in the top of the form, and in the bottom of the form I show the rotated coordinates.

Notice that in the image below, a simple rotation of a coordinate of Y10.0 around Z axis by 90 degrees return a correct X value (-10), but Y shows a funky number (6.1230...)... However if I change the rotation angle around Z to 45, the results seems to be correct...

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong to get this weird Y. Because of this error, I´m not trusting in the results of this algorithm at all but I´m currently in a blindspot...

[image: Conceptual UI]

This is the code of the calculate button:

```
 Private Sub BtnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCompute.Click

    'Capture the values from the text boxes and parse then to doubles
    ValidateAllFieldsWithDoubleValues()

    'Rotate the coordinates
    RotateXYZCoordinates(dblOriginalCoordX, dblOriginalCoordY, dblOriginalCoordZ, dblCurrentRotationAroundX, dblCurrentRotationAroundY, dblCurrentRotationAroundZ)

    'Update the text boxes for the rotated coordinates for XYZ
    txtResultX.Text = dblResultX.ToString
    txtResultY.Text = dblResultY.ToString
    txtResultZ.Text = dblResultZ.ToString

End Sub
```

And this is the code of the function that calculates the rotations:

```
Private Function RotateXYZCoordinates(ByVal XCoord As Double, ByVal YCoord As Double, ByVal ZCoord As Double, ByVal Pitch As Double, ByVal Roll As Double, ByVal Yaw As Double)

    'X Rotation
    Dim RadPitch As Double = 0
    Dim CosPitch As Double = 0
    Dim SinPitch As Double = 0
    Dim XRotatedAroundX As Double = 0
    Dim YRotatedAroundX As Double = 0
    Dim ZRotatedAroundX As Double = 0
    RadPitch = Pitch * Math.PI / 180
    CosPitch = Math.Cos(RadPitch)
    SinPitch = Math.Sin(RadPitch)

    XRotatedAroundX = XCoord
    YRotatedAroundX = YCoord * CosPitch - ZCoord * SinPitch
    ZRotatedAroundX = YCoord * SinPitch + ZCoord * CosPitch

    'Y Rotation
    Dim RadRoll As Double = 0
    Dim CosRoll As Double = 0
    Dim SinRoll As Double = 0
    Dim XRotatedAroundY As Double = 0
    Dim YRotatedAroundY As Double = 0
    Dim ZRotatedAroundY As Double = 0
    RadRoll = Roll * Math.PI / 180
    CosRoll = Math.Cos(RadRoll)
    SinRoll = Math.Sin(RadRoll)

    XRotatedAroundY = ZRotatedAroundX * CosRoll - XRotatedAroundX * SinRoll
    YRotatedAroundY = YRotatedAroundX
    ZRotatedAroundY = ZRotatedAroundX * SinRoll + XRotatedAroundX * CosRoll

    'Z Rotation
    Dim RadYaw As Double = 0
    Dim CosYaw As Double = 0
    Dim SinYaw As Double = 0
    Dim XRotatedAroundZ As Double = 0
    Dim YRotatedAroundZ As Double = 0
    Dim ZRotatedAroundZ As Double = 0
    RadYaw = Yaw * Math.PI / 180
    CosYaw = Math.Cos(RadYaw)
    SinYaw = Math.Sin(RadYaw)

    XRotatedAroundZ = XRotatedAroundY * CosYaw - YRotatedAroundY * SinYaw
    YRotatedAroundZ = XRotatedAroundY * SinYaw + YRotatedAroundY * CosYaw
    ZRotatedAroundZ = ZRotatedAroundY

    'Final result

    dblResultX = XRotatedAroundZ
    dblResultY = YRotatedAroundZ
    dblResultZ = ZRotatedAroundZ

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

I know this is not an elegant code but it is what I can code for now... I´d appreciate if someone could take a look at this and point me to the source of error... I´ve been watching videos and did an extensive search in this website before I posted... But it seems some things are still very advanced to me for now... I´m not lazy and I´m willing to learn if someone point me towards something I could digest for now...

If someone could share a hint about how to make this rotate function to support rotation around a point other than 0,0,0 I´d appreciate.

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: Rotating around another point is usually just done via translate-rotate-translate.

Comment: On first sight, your code looks ok. Are you sure that the result is actually `6.1...` and not `6.1...e-...`, which would be pretty close to zero and therefore correct? Maybe, the textbox is just cutting the final `e-...` part.

Comment: Yes @NicoSchertler - That was the issue... But I´m still lost about hot to rotate in 3D about an arbitrary point... It only works through 0,0,0

Comment: Subtract the pivot point from your vector, then do the rotation, and add the pivot back.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct. Due to double precision math and a 90 degree rotation there is a limit to the accuracy. The answer is really 6.12303176911189E-16 or .000000000000000612303176911189. Round the number off to a realistic value of decimal points. This is also why 1+1 is not equal to 2 but 1.999999999999999999999999999999 in floating point math.